# VB.net Redirecting Real Time process output

Tags: vb.net, process, redirectstandardoutput

I have a problem with redirect real time process output, I'm running a **java .jar file** from 
vb.net process, and i want to redirect it. I created a console form, with richtextbox.
The arguments are long, so I'm not write there. The code (it isn't redirecting anyithing) :

```
console.show() 'Console is a console window...
dim p as new process
p.startinfo.filename = java '(java as string: C:\Program Files\java....)
p.startinfo.argument = "-Xms2048M -Xmx4096M...."
p.startinfo.redirectstandardoutput = true
'what is comme there?
console.richtextbox1.text = 'and here is a redirected output, but i want redirect real time.
```

Thx any ideas, and helpful answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was solved, the answer:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

dim p as process()
p.startinfo.filename = "xyz"
p.startinfo.arguments = "...."
p.startinfo.workingdirectory = "some path"
p.startinfo.redirectstandarderror = true
p.startinfo.redirectstandardoutput = true
p.enableraisingevents = True
Application.DoEvents()
AddHandler proc.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
AddHandler proc.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
p.start()
proc.BeginErrorReadLine()
proc.BeginOutputReadLine()

End Sub

Delegate Sub UpdateTextBoxDelg(text As String)
    Public myDelegate As UpdateTextBoxDelg = New UpdateTextBoxDelg(AddressOf UpdateTextBox)
    Public Sub UpdateTextBox(text As String)
        Console.RichTextBox1.Text += text & Environment.NewLine
        Console.RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = Console.RichTextBox1.Text.Length
        Console.RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub

    Public Sub proc_OutputDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then
            Me.Invoke(myDelegate, e.Data)
        Else
            UpdateTextBox(e.Data)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to start the process.

```
p.Start()
```

Comment: Ok, yes I forgot, but this is not answer for the question.

Comment: @ProGamingHun You said it does not work. This is the reason with your current code.

Comment: Pls post real answer for the question: How To Redirect In VB.NET Process Standard Output in Real Time?.